# Wordpress create a child theme from a child theme :S

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

I get blocked trying to create a child theme for Orfeo, which is an already child theme from Hestia, both from Themeisle. Is there anyway to do it?

This is the style.css header of Orfeo, don't know how to build the one for orfeo-child:

```
   /*
Theme Name:     Orfeo
Theme URI:      https://themeisle.com/themes/orfeo/
Author:         ThemeIsle
Author URI:     https://themeisle.com
Description:    Orfeo is a responsive WordPress theme with multipurpose design. It is a good fit for both small businesses and corporate businesses, as it is highly customizable via the Live Customizer. You can use Orfeo for restaurants, startups, freelancer resume, creative agencies, portfolios, WooCommerce, or niches like sports, medical, blogging, fashion, lawyer sites etc. It has a one-page design, Sendinblue newsletter integration, widgetized footer, and a clean appearance. The theme is compatible with Elementor Page Builder, Photo Gallery, Flat Parallax Slider, and Travel Map; it is mobile friendly and optimized for SEO.
Version:        1.0.5
License:        GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI:    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain:    orfeo
Template:       hestia
Tags: blog, custom-logo, portfolio, e-commerce, rtl-language-support, post-formats, grid-layout, one-column, two-columns, custom-background, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, featured-image-header, featured-images, flexible-header, full-width-template, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, translation-ready

This theme, like WordPress, is licensed under the GPL.
Use it to make something cool, have fun, and share what you've learned with others.

*/
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress child theme of a child theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913744/wordpress-child-theme-of-a-child-theme)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress themes cannot have "grandchildren". So, no, you cannot do that :)
Instead, you can just copy it and use it as a basis for your own child theme.

Comment: Thanks @svelon, I was afraid it was the only answer :) Of course I've managed this option but expected to find "other way" to manage it.

Comment: Just was trying the same thing with Orfeo...
Taking svelons answer as basis I will try to cleverly overwrite:
copy Orfeo and give it a new name
- add a different stylesheet (e.g. style_grandchild.css)
- link this new child-theme inside functions.php 
- extend functions.php as usual (though a second functions would be ideal).            The main idea is to change Orfeo so that when updates are delivered, a integration of the new Orfeo code overwrites as little grandchild code as possible. Obviously the new child theme will not be updated, but separation is useful when merging